# Excel addin installer creates 2 uninstall entries

Tags: excel, installation, vsto, add-in, visual-studio-setup-proje

The installer (created using Visual Studio 2017's setup project template) creates 2 entries in the Apps & features list for my VSTO Excel add-in.  One entry gets created immediately after running the msi; a second after running Excel and agreeing to install the add-in.
The 2 entries have the same name.  One has a size associated with it. The second does not.

How can I modify my set-up project so that only 1 entry is created?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you mixed `MSI` and `ClickOnce` installers into a single setup program. I'd recommend going through the steps described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer).

### Deploying a Solution by Using ClickOnce

When you deploy a solution by using ClickOnce, you publish it to a central location where users can install and run it. You can update the solution without having to distribute a new setup program to users.  This deployment option is simpler, but you can't show users custom setup pages. Also, solutions must be installed multiple times on any computer that has more than one user. Read more about that in the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) article.

### Deploying a Solution by Using Windows Installer

When you deploy a solution by using Windows Installer, you distribute a setup program to users, and users install the solution by using that program. The setup program can install a solution for all users of a computer at the same time, rather than the current user only. You also have a bit more control over options that appear to users when they install your solution. For example, you can show a licensing agreement or enable users to install specific components of a solution. However, if you update the solution, you must distribute a new setup program. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, Eugene!  It was the '|vstolocal' that was missing from the end of the manifest string. Once I added that, the installer behaved as expected.